# Rails - Case Monitoring App - Want to display data from 2 tables in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Model:

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee, :foreign_key => :input_id
end
```

Controller

```
def index
  @cases = Case.all
end
```

View

```
<% @cases.each do |c| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= c.employee.name %></td>
    <td><%= c.problem %></td>
    <td><%= c.assigned_id %></td>
    <td><%= c.solution %></td>
    <td><%= c.verified_id %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

How do I make the view display the employee name who owns the assigned_id?
(I'm already using employee.name to display the name for the input_id column?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two reflections

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee, :foreign_key => :input_id
  belongs_to :assigned_employee, :foreign_key => : assigned_id, : class_name => "Employee"
end
```

In the View

```
<% @cases.each do |c| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= c.employee.name %></td>
  <td><%= c.assigned_employee.name %></td>
```